# prevent double include of jquery

Tags: jquery, grails

I'm using the jquery-ui and resources plugins. In my config.groovy, I have

```
grails.views.javascript.library="jquery"
```

and some modules

```
grails.resources.modules = {
  cluetip {
     dependsOn 'jquery-ui'
     resource url:'css/jquery.cluetip.css'
     resource url:'js/jquery.cluetip.min.js'
  }
}
```

This works all fine, except that the generated HTML contains a double
include of jquery

```
<script src="/static/plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
[...]
<script type="text/javascript" src="/plugins/jquery-1.6.1.1/js/jquery/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
```

How can I prevent this?

Forgot to mention: I'm using grails 1.3.7

**Edit**

In my layout I have

```
<r:layoutResources/>
<g:javascript library="jquery" plugin="jquery"/>
```

The last line is the problem and must be removed - Thanks to Stefan. I marked his answer as correct, but please read the comments.

Christian

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO the best way to deal with this is using the [Grails Resources plugin](http://grails-plugins.github.com/grails-resources/).

Comment: I'm already using the resources plugin - as I wrote in the first line. But I don't know how to configure it to prevent the double include.

Comment: Sorry, didn't read your question carefully enough. Resources plugin normally prevents duplicated resources. Grep your grails-app/views directory recursivly for usages of <g:javascript> or occurences of <script> tag. I'm almost sure there is a non-zero sized resultset.

Comment: Try to exchange the order of the two tags.

Comment: Puuh, I hope this doesn't become too confusing. Finally you where right. Removing the <g:javascript ...> was the solution. That formRemote didn't work, was caused by a change in config.groovy.